# I am failing to access property.yml files located in a sub folder in git using spring cloud config server in one of my microservices

Tags: java, spring, cloud, microservices, config

i have a config repo as follows

config-repo:

**service1:**

```
 - service1.yml

 - service1-dev.yml

 - service1-prod.yml
```

**service2:**

```
 - service2.yml

 - service2-dev.yml

 - service2-prod.yml
```

then i have the following configs in my config server
spring:
cloud :
config:
server:
git:
uri:uri here
search-paths:
- '*/**' 'also tried '{application}' and '{application}/{application}-{profile}'
username: *****
password: *****
cloneOnStart: true
force-pull: true

Output on application startup

2023-08-28 12:53:04,954 - DEBUG z.c.e.s.ServiceCustomer - Running with Spring Boot v2.7.2, Spring v5.3.21
2023-08-28 12:53:04,955 - DEBUG o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class zw.co.econet.serviceapplications.ServiceApplications
2023-08-28 12:53:04,997 - INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader - Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:7001/
2023-08-28 12:53:04,998 - INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader - Located environment: name=service1, profiles=[default], label=null, version=376b3a7b8edd20d26161873656fb41bc080d5334, state=null
2023-08-28 12:53:04,998 - DEBUG o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader - Environment service1 has 1 property sources with 1 properties.

Microservice A and B are failing to startup as they cannot pick up the property files on git please help.

search-paths:

- '*/**' 'also tried '{application}' and '{application}/{application}-{profile}'

Microservice A and B are failing to startup as they cannot pick up the property files on git please help.

Comment: I am able to pull the config properties for Service1 when i pull them via the config server directly but i am not able to get my microservices  to pull the properties